# Apache htaccess redirect to https all urls except certain one with various parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect to HTTPS all urls which are not secure, except a custom url which includes various parameters.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/code-validator/?code=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

So http://example.com/code-validator/?code=123 or any parameter on this url will not be redirected to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` to be able to:

1. Match query string since `REQUEST_URI` only matches URI without query string
2. Get access to unmodified original URL as received by Apache

Your rule can be:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/code-validator/\?code= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to keep this rule as your topmost rule and also clear old browser cache.

Comment: So clever and wonderful. I would not have guessed. Thank you so much!